# Microsoft R Server SQL NULL/Missing values

Tags: sql-server, r, microsoft-r

I am having a bit of on issue using RxSqlServerData() in Microsoft R to import a table from a SQL Server database. My database in SQL server contains rows that have both blanks and NULL values. When I run RxSqlServerData, these both get imported as "missing" values, specifically, `<NA>`

Is there something I can specify in the `colInfo` argument that could import these as factors, say, "None" or something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the same result with RODBC or odbc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after you have imported the data you can use the `rxDataStep` function, and in the `transforms` argument, you define how your missing values should be handled.

An example of this is, where I have a table with some columns and some of the columns have null values or - in the case of string columns - potentially empty string. My table definition looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tb_MissingValue(RowID int identity PRIMARY KEY,
                                 Col1 int,
                                 Col2 int,
                                 Col3 varchar(50))
```

And I have inserted data like so:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tb_MissingValue(Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES (1, null, 'Hello'),
        (null, 2, 'world'),
        (3, 1, ''),
        (4, 2, 'Again');
```

My R code looks like this to retrieve the data from the database:

```
connString <- "Driver=SQL Server;
               Server=win10-dev; 
               Database=RTest;
               Uid=sa;
               Pwd=secret_stuff"

missingData <- RxSqlServerData(connectionString = connString, 
                 sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tb_MissingValue")
```

Looking at the data in the `missingData` data frame it looks like so:

```
  RowID Col1 Col2  Col3
  1     1    1   NA Hello
  2     2   NA    2 world
  3     3    3    1  <NA>
  4     4    4    2 Again
```

At this stage what I can do is to use the `rxDataStep` function and the `transforms` argument, like I mentioned above:

```
nonMissing <- rxDataStep(inData = missingData,
                     transforms = list(
                     Col1 = ifelse(is.na(Col1), "Missing", Col1),
                     Col2 = ifelse(is.na(Col2), "Missing", Col2),
                     Col3 = ifelse(is.na(Col3), "Missing", Col3)))
```

Then when I view the data `nonMissing`, I get this:

```
  RowID    Col1    Col2    Col3
  1     1       1 Missing   Hello
  2     2 Missing       2   world
  3     3       3       1 Missing
  4     4       4       2   Again
```

You could of course also handle the missing values in your original query. That's probably what I'd do.

Hope this helps!

Niels